# Search for sub string that contains dash and space in EleasticSearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a model like this:

```cs
public class PersonModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public PersonageType Type { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string NationalCode { get; set; }

    public string BourseCode { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to implement a query to filter data that match the substring of each property:

```cs
var result = await ElasticClient.SearchAsync<PersonModel>(sd => sd
    .Index(IndexName)
    .From((pagination.PageNumber - 1) * pagination.PageSize)
    .Size(pagination.PageSize)
    .Query(q =>
        +q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Type).Query(typeValue)) &&
        +q.Wildcard(w => w.Field(f => f.NationalCode).Value(nationalCode == null ? null : $"*{nationalCode}*")) &&
        +q.Wildcard(w => w.Field(f => f.Name).Value(name == null ? null : $"*{name}*")) &&
        +q.Wildcard(w => w.Field(f => f.BourseCode).Value(bourseCode == null ? null : $"*{bourseCode}*"))));
```

This query works fine but when each value contains `-` or `white space`, nothing will be returned. For example, I have a person with the name `john doe` and when `name` value is `hn d`, the search query doesn't work.

Comment: can you please share some sample data and expected search result in JSON format ?

Comment: the problem is in standard analyzer and using wildcard query( this problem answered too many times). if you insist in use wildcard query, you should use "keyword" mapping type. otherwise describe what you want to do, so we could help you redesigning your mapping and query.

Comment: @hamid It would be great if you send me one of those links that answered this problem. I just want to write a query similar to %like% in SQL Server and it make no difference to me to use the wildcard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the easiest approach for solving this problem is to change your mapping.
try something as below:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "NationalCode": {
        "type":  "keyword"
      },
      "Name": {
        "type":  "keyword"
      },
      "BourseCode": {
        "type":  "keyword"
      },
    }
  }
}
```

then reindex your data.

for more information:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html

I think you are using text field datatype. also if you want to use match query and enjoy its benefits you can have both type as below:

```
PUT my-index-000001
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "NationalCode": { 
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": { 
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

then you can use match query against `NationalCode` and wildcard query against `NationalCode.keyword`

Answer (score 2):

As @hamid said `keyword` fixed the problem and I changed the query to this:

```cs
var result = await ElasticClient.SearchAsync<PersonageSearchReadModel>(sd => sd
    .Index(IndexName)
    .From((pagination.PageNumber - 1) * pagination.PageSize)
    .Size(pagination.PageSize)
    .Query(q =>
        +q.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Type).Query(typeValue)) &&
        +q.Wildcard(w => w.Field(f => f.NationalCode.Suffix("keyword")).Value(nationalCode == null ? null : $"*{nationalCode}*")) &&
        +q.Wildcard(w => w.Field(f => f.Name.Suffix("keyword")).Value(name == null ? null : $"*{name}*")) &&
        +q.Wildcard(w => w.Field(f => f.BourseCode.Suffix("keyword")).Value(bourseCode == null ? null : $"*{bourseCode}*"))));
```